# Is Compare Pulse sooner than OC1REF in STM32 Advanced Timer output trigger

Tags: stm32, timer

The options for trigger output signals seem not very well documented. According to the datasheet (P509, [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00305666.pdf)) they include:

Compare Pulse - The trigger output send a positive pulse when the CC1IF flag is to be set (even if it was already high), as soon as a capture or a compare match occurred.

OC1REF signal is used as trigger output (TRGO)
OC2REF signal is used as trigger output (TRGO)
OC3REF signal is used as trigger output (TRGO)
OC4REF signal is used as trigger output (TRGO)

I'm interested in the difference between Compare Pulse and OC1REF. 
I understand that either of these should cause a trigger when a capture occurs on CC channel 1, so what is the difference between the two.

The wording suggests that Compare Pulse might occur sooner in time than OC1REF, I would be grateful if someone can confirm whether this is the case or not, thanks.

In the StdPeriph lib, the function is TIM_SelectOutputTrigger and the options in question are TIM_TRGOSource_OC1 vs. TIM_TRGOSource_OC1Ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> either of these should cause a trigger when a capture occurs on CC channel 1

When a *capture* occurs on a channel, then that channel is in *input* mode, and OCxREF is *undefined* as far as I know. OCxREF is never ever mentioned in the chapters and register descriptions dealing with input modes.

In output modes, they are quite different.

A **Compare Pulse** is generated whenever `CCRx == CNT`, possibly limited by the `CMS` bits in `CR1`. As the name suggests, it is a pulse that goes high when the match is detected, and goes low again after a short (but unspecified) amount of time.

The function of the **OCxREF** signal is controlled by the `OCxM` bits in `CCMR`. It *can* be configured to go high when `CCRx == CNT`. The exact wording is

> 110: PWM mode 1 - In upcounting, channel 1 is active as long as TIMx_CNT < TIMx_CCR1
>   else inactive. In downcounting, channel 1 is inactive (OC1REF=‘0) as long as
>   TIMx_CNT > TIMx_CCR1 else active (OC1REF=1).
>
> 111: PWM mode 2 - In upcounting, channel 1 is inactive as long as TIMx_CNT < TIMx_CCR1 else active. In downcounting, channel 1 is active as long as TIMx_CNT > TIMx_CCR1 else inactive.

So it'd go high when `CCRx == CNT` in PWM Mode 1 downcounting phase, or in PWM Mode 2 upcounting phase. Otherwise (in these modes) it'd trigger at the update event (counter rollover).

Figures 119 and 120 in the linked reference manual *suggest* that it happens synchronously with the compare pulse.

Another important difference is that OCxREF can in some configurations go high and remain high (until some external trigger or software action resets it), not triggering the slave when `CNT` matches `CCR` *again*.

Comment: Looks like my use of the word "capture" was incorrect in this context. Thanks for your clear and detailed answer.